# Make Eloquent Alias for connection('something')

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I would like to make a alias for Eloquent.

I would like it to be possible to run `User::draft->all();` where this should be the same as `User::connection('draft')->all();`.

Does anyone knows how I can do this?

I have tried the following:

```
class CustomBuilder extends \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
{
    public function draft()
    {
        $this->setConnection('draft');
        return $this;
    }
}

class MyModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
    {
        $conn = $this->getConnection();
        $grammar = $conn->getQueryGrammar();
        return new CustomBuilder($conn, $grammar, $conn->getPostProcessor());
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I get the following error: `Call to undefined method CustomBuilder::setConnection()`

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` does not have a method `setConnection`

Comment: Thanks @matt-burrow, I figured that out. But what I need is another way to change the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do this as personally i would do;

```
User::on('draft')->all();
```

As this explains the code within the code. Following does not without having to explore your code.

But if you want you could try adding this method to your model;

```
public static function draft(){
    $instance = new static;
    $instance->setConnection('draft');
    return $instance->newQuery();
}
```

So then you can do `User::draft()->all()`.

Personally, I would use the `on` method, but the second has not been tested.

EDIT: after looking setConnection is not a static method. So the on method is the way to go.